# How can I show live stream of video in H.264 format via RTMP on mobile browser?

Tags: android, video-streaming, h.264, rtmp, live-streaming

How can I show live stream of video in H.264 format via RTMP on mobile browser ? I tried many ways but none is working on mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

RTMP is only available in flash.

Comment: Will it be compatible with android mobile browser ? If so, can you please tell me how can I do this ?

Comment: Some version of android yes, other no. For iOS you MUST use HLS if you content is over 5 minutes. So I generally recommend HLS everywhere.

Comment: can u please help me out with any code for this. For running live streaming on android mobile browser.

Comment: No, I can not. But I can answer specific questions you post on stack overflow. If you are not far enough along in your project to have specific questions, you need to do more research on your own. I suggest you start with video.js or jwplayer.